# Exclude test folder from maven build

Tags: java, maven

This is one of the most asked questions here in so... but why any answer works for me? i believe i have somehow a wrong maven structure in my project

I have a project like

```
basedir
|-src
|--many many many packages
|-test
|--testpackages
|-pom.xml
```

So my `pom.xml` is in the same level as `src` and `test` folders and it isn't the typical structure like java/main/ java/test... it is the root of the project folder

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/test</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                <excludes>
                <exclude>**/test/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
                </configuration>


            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

but when i run maven install and open the generated jar the folder test is in there...
how can i solve and make it ignore this folder?

Comment: <exclude>test/**</exclude>

Answer (score 2):

Add `-DskipTests` to `mvn` command as a workaround. For instance:

```
mvn package -DskipTests
```

Comment: didn't work... i dont know if i wasn't clear, but the problem is that the test folder is INSIDE the final jar.... is not that maven is running test code

Comment: @RafaelLima , if the folder is is final jar then it is already built, how and what you wanna achieve next with maven? Beside all **Nilanjan's** answer is correct in most cases.

Comment: @Common Man: `-DskipTests` option will skip the test case run only, it won't prevent the **test** folder from getting packaged if it is at the same level as **src** and not inside it:(`<testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/test</testSourceDirectory>`)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I believe your maven project structure is not correct. Maven excludes `src/test/java` for packaging by default so **test** folder should be inside **src** and not in the same level as shown below:

[image]

For more details visit [Maven doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/)